# Call to a member function add() on string

Tags: laravel, carbon

Para obtener una fecha de un formulario y añadirle horas una variable que contiene las horas para asi obtener una fecha estimada

```
'fecha_inicio'=>$this->startdate, 
'fecha_estimada'=>$this->startdate->add($this->horas, 'hours'),
```

he intentado con eso pero me resulta un error

> Call to a member function add() on string

Estoy usando laravel 8 y Carbon

Comment: ¿Qué valor contiene la propiedad `$startdate`?, si puedes agrégalo a tu pregunta

Comment: Contiene el valor que el usuario da del formulario como fecha inicial

Comment: De ahi el problema, no puedes agregar por ejemplo horas de forma directa por que ese valor es solo una cadena de texto, necesitas me parece el método parse de Carbon, te sugiero busques al respecto

Comment: De acuerdo, muchas gracias

Comment: Además ¿en qué formato llega la fecha?

Comment: Además ¿en qué formato viene la fecha que manda el usuario?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que convertir **startdate** a **Carbon** para ello usa **createFromFormat**

```
$fecha_inicio = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $this->startdate);
```

y después ya podrás usar el

```
$fecha_inicio->add($this->horas, 'hours')
```